# How to enable /INCREMENTAL:YES for release builds with cmake on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I need to use the linker flag `/INCREMENTAL:YES` when building some libraries with Visual Studio, but cmake seems to insist on using `/INCREMENTAL:NO` with release builds, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Some of the stuff that I've tried is

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "/INCREMENTAL:YES")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/INCREMENTAL:YES")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "/INCREMENTAL:YES")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "/INCREMENTAL:YES")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/INCREMENTAL:YES ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
```

Nothing fixes the problem. As far as I can tell, cmake is just plain hardwired to think that a release build must use `/INCREMENTAL:NO`. Does anyone know how to fix that and make it use `/INCREMENTAL:YES`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've check *CMakeCache.txt* file and found more flags:

```
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
```

But I can't verify my assumption, seems like simply updating `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` works fine for me (MSVC 2012, CMake 2.8.10), `/INCREMENTAL:NO` changed to `/INCREMENTAL`.

Comment: `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` worked. `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` didn't. Thanks!