# use CMAKE to set enable incremental linking to NO in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am using cmake 2.8.0 to build my VS2012 solution that has multiple projects. For each project, I wish to set the properties->Linker-> **Enable Incremental Linking** to **NO** for each project.

There are flags such as **CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG** that can probably be used. I am not sure though, tried some online help as well to no effect.

Please advise

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501121

Answer (score 2):

You should set the [`/INCREMENTAL:NO` linker flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To override it in CMake, you should follow the techniques provided in [How to add linker or compile flag in cmake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11783932/1619294):

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /INCREMENTAL:NO" )
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach and it does not work. Does it work at your end?

I also read somewhere that the following line has to be added above project `SET(MSVC_INCREMENTAL_DEFAULT ON)
PROJECT(XXX)`

Is it correct?

Comment: This does not work. Somewhere deep in the bowels of CMAKE, it sets "/INCREMENTAL:YES" by default and adding "/INCREMENTAL:NO" to CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS does not override this.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the solution. Apparently a lot of other flags also need to be set to **/INCREMENTAL:NO**

```
FOREACH(FLAG_TYPE EXE MODULE SHARED)
    STRING (REPLACE "INCREMENTAL:YES" "INCREMENTAL:NO" FLAG_TMP 
    "${CMAKE_${FLAG_TYPE}_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
        STRING (REPLACE "/EDITANDCONTINUE" "" FLAG_TMP 
    "${CMAKE_${FLAG_TYPE}_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
        SET(CMAKE_${FLAG_TYPE}_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "/INCREMENTAL:NO ${FLAG_TMP}" CACHE
        STRING "Overriding default debug ${FLAG_TYPE} linker flags." FORCE)
        MARK_AS_ADVANCED (CMAKE_${FLAG_TYPE}_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG)
ENDFOREACH ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that works for me is:

```
if(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/INCREMENTAL:NO")
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking `WIN32` is not enough. [The flag only means that the target system is Windows.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/WIN32.html)
So, in case we are building with `GCC` or any other compiler on Windows, the flag `/INCREMENTAL` would fail because it is `MSVC` specific.

for CMake >= 3.13 this should do it.

```
if(MSVC) 
    target_link_options(${TARGET_NAME} <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>
        # $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/INCREMENTAL> is active by default for debug
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/INCREMENTAL:NO>
    )
endif()
```

[target_link_options docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html)